# DIsplay the list of all categories in magento

Tags: category

I want to display the list of all category into which the particular product belongs .This information is neede to display all category in product view page.

Comment: simply the product category levels right? `getCategoryIds()` list all category ids for a product.

Answer (score 1):

The following code belongs in `app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`:

```
$category_ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($category_ids as $category_id) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $category->getName() . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Will it list all categories?

Comment: Yes. In future try and test the code before you decide to post comment questions.